# npm install -g @mimik/mimik-edge-cli does not work on raspbian

Tags: edgesdk

I am working on Raspbian and trying to get edge access token for raspberry pi node. But it is not able to install **mimik edge CLI tool** in Raspbian. due to the following issues.
[image]

How will I get the edge Access token Token for raspberry pi, because the procedure for the same has changed in the website.(*No section to enter the IP address of Raspberry pi*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have internet connection on your PI. Also verify that npm/node is installed correctly and globally. When you input below in terminal:

```
node -v
```

and

```
npm -v
```

you should get the version running on your PI. If the above commands do NOT work, you will need to fix your environment issues before trying to install and run mimik-edge-cli tool.